# How to Read the value of below json in controller.js. As i have to set the value in controller.js only

Tags: angularjs

Let Me know how to access the value of response by looking to the below json data

**Login Controller**

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope,$http, $location, 
   $rootScope,$window) {
      $scope.submit = function(){
      $rootScope.userName=$scope.username;
      var username=$scope.username;
      var password=$scope.password;
      $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'http://localhost:8082/APIGateway/APILoginService/login',
             data: jsonData,
             headers : {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 'Orgkey': 'S2lyYW5fcmFqYWdvcGFs'
             }         
         })
         .then(function successCallback(response) {
         if(response.data.code=="Invalid loginId or password" || response.data.message=="Invalid loginId or password"){
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Invalid LoginId/Password';
         } else {
             $rootScope.loggedIn=true;
             $rootScope.userName = response.data.APIUserData;
             $rootScope.roleName=response.data.roleName;      
         } 
     },         
  };
});
```

This is The json data.

```
    {
        "APIUserData": [
            {
                "userID": "deve",
                "firstName": "De",
                "lastName": "Singh",
                "mobileNumber": "990064533",
                "emailID": "xyz@gmail.com",
                "roleID": 1,
                "Org_Id": 1,
                "status": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am facing problem because of APIUserData. If i remove it i can easily access the value. can anybody help me in fixing the issue

Answer (score 0):

APIUserData is an array. You could do something like this:

```
var myResponse = {
        "APIUserData": [
            {
                "userID": "deve",
                "firstName": "De",
                "lastName": "Singh",
                "mobileNumber": "990064533",
                "emailID": "xyz@gmail.com",
                "roleID": 1,
                "Org_Id": 1,
                "status": 1
            }
        ]
    };

var roleID = myResponse.APIUserData[0].roleID;
```